# IsDirty using INotifyPropertyChanged for EF entity

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

Given a std record edit form using WPF two way binding to a EF entity object

The IsDirty is handled as follows

```
entity.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(ct_PropertyChanged);
DataContext = entity;

void entity_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IsDirty = true;
}

void SaveAndClose()
{
    if ( IsDirty ) { // doSave }
    Close();
}
```

Everything works great except if the user changes just fieldX and hits save ( which is a valid model in this case !)

The problem is PropertyChanged() is NOT called till Close() executes so the record is NOT saved

Any way to force the "Binder" or any other alternatives ?

Comment: The two answers above are missing the point.  When you press the 'Save & Close' button any other control will lose focus, binding will occur and PropertyChange will fire.
I have created a simple test app based on your description where everything works correctly.  Unfortunately that means I can't offer you a solution.  Can you post more code/xaml?

Comment: Of course the other point to make is that the Entity Framework ObjectContext is tracking all changes for you, so you only need to call myEntities.SaveChanges() since it already knows that an object is dirty.

Comment: @Phil  button_click is called before entity_PropertyChanged, that's the problem

Comment: What versions of .net etc are you using?

Comment: @Phil .net 4, vs 2010  though this shd have no impact, i vaguely recall something similar in winforms ages ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the `UpdateSourceTrigger` is `LostFocus` so the Property is updated when the control (filedX) loses the focus. E.g. the user clicks sets the cursor into an other control.

One possibility is, to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`.

Another way is to force the currently focused element to update the source.

Here is an example for a TextBox:

```
var focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
if(focusedElement is TextBox)
{
    var bindingExpression = ((TextBox)focusedElement).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    if(bindingExpression != null)
    {
        bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

Comment: GetBindingExpression() always returns null for whatever reason, any ideas ?

Comment: Should the be a Binding for the Property you are passing to the Method?

Comment: yup and that's why it's so surprising, any ideas on how to debug this? or perhaps get a list of bindings for the control ?

Comment: You loose the Binding if you assign a concrete value to the property of the control. In this case the binding will be null.
But I don't think that's the case.

Comment: Have you tried to change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to solve you initial Problem?

Comment: didn't understand this "You loose the Binding if you assign a concrete value to the property of the control. " the value is bound to the text property fyi

Comment: It means if you bind something to the Text property and afterwards you do something like `myTextbox.Text = "SOME STRING"` the binding is dropped. I don't think that's the case, but I have no idea what else could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The default Binding UpdateSourceTrigger is LostFocus which means that your binding will update the underlaying value when your control will loses Focus. 
You can change that to PropertyChanged so it will update the source as soon as the user clicks it (or types in if it's a TextBox).